# iPhone - core data - getting an object from one entity based on a relationship on another

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have two core data entities. Lets call them `AAA` and `BBB`.

`BBB` contains a relationship to `AAA`, one to one.

When I create a new `BBB` entry, I do (at this point `myA` is one entry on `AAA`):

```
BBB *item = nil;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BBB" inManagedObjectContext:context];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(relation == %@)", myA];

NSError *error = nil;
item = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
[request release];

if (!error && !umItem) {  // if there's no item, create a new one
    item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BBB" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    item.relation = myA;  // to create a relation from BBB to AAA
}
```

at some point in time, I have just a list of `BBB` objects. Remember that each `BBB` object has a property called `relation` pointing to `AAA`.

Now, how do I retrieve `AAA`?

Is it enough to do

```
AAA *myAAA = (AAA*)myBBB.relation;
```

is this `relation` the object itself on `AAA`?

how do I do that?
thanks

Comment: Don't cast returns of managed objects. It can cause subtle bugs if you return a generic NSManagedObject or another subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by calling `myBBB.relation;` (dynamic typing is not needful if `relation` is of type `AAA`) you will get object of class `AAA` or `nil`. If `relation` is not optional then before `committing` changes you should define that relationship to all updated/new objects.

Comment: +1 Never fetch if you already have a relationship object in hand.